# Terraform apply - ignore cost estimation

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm running a terraform apply -auto-approve command to update one resource in Azure and it's hanging up on the Cost Estimation part taking more than 7 minutes to move on (sometimes longer than that).  Is there a param to pass that will skip the cost estimation piece of a terraform apply command?

Comment: This is with Terraform Cloud/Enterprise?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is only available in Terraform Enterprise. Have you tried to reach out to them through support?

https://www.terraform.io/docs/enterprise/support/index.html